# PayPal SDK: User Pays, then hits home before Done

Tags: android

I've encountered a scenario in which a user enters the PayPal flow and purchases a ticket. Then, instead of clicking Done to return to the main Activity, the user clicks Home and returns home. The Activity is then killed.

In that usecase, the payment information from PayPal is never returned to the app, so the app has no way of knowing that it should have updated its information in the databases and for the UI. It's as if the user never paid in the first place, minus the hole in their wallet...

Saving the data before entering the processing won't be a solution either, as in this usecase it's as if no payment ever took place since no payment information is ever returned to the Activity.

Anyone have any thoughts?

If only there was a way to skip PayPal's Done page and just automatically return....

Comment: Using this: https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/integration/mobile/android-integration-guide/?

Comment: What happens when you return to the application? Does it show the Done screen? Does it crash? Does it show your `Activity` that called the API in the first place?

Comment: No, it functions correctly when the user finishes the flow. This is a scenario when the user does not finish from PayPal but closes the application before it has returned any data; thus there is no way for the app to know that the user has paid.

Comment: So after `the user clicks Home and returns home. The Activity is then killed.` and  2 hours later returns to application it shows the Done screen and they can click Done? I don't really understand the issue here then.

Comment: They don't return to done, that is the issue. And your answer below leads me to believe it's me incorrectly handling the instance. I'll have to check it out tomorrow

Answer (score 0):

Then I guess you are better of asking their support team.

I don't know the API, but IMHO they should provide some way to read the proof of payment the other way, that is polling for it.

If `onActivityResult` is the only way, then that's very, very bad API. User may kill the application while on the `PaymentCompletedActivity`.

From your description I also feel like they have a bug and don't use `onSaveInsatnceState` to preserve the state when the application process is killed by the system. Read the comment under question, so we may clarify that.

Comment: Maybe they do, actually, and maybe it's me incorrectly handling the onSaveInstance. I'll have to look into that and get back to you. Thanks